# Can the Google traffic layer be added to an OpenLayers 2 map without displaying a Google base map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, openlayers

I know I can add a Google map to an OpenLayers 2 map as an OpenLayers.Layer.Google(.v3) layer and can add the traffic layer to the included map using code like:

```
var map;

function init() {
    map = new OpenLayers.Map('map');
    map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());

    var gphy = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
        "Google Physical",
        {type: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN}
    );
    var gmap = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
        "Google Streets", // the default
        {numZoomLevels: 20}
    );

    map.addLayers([gmap, gphy]);

    var trafficLayer = new google.maps.TrafficLayer();
    trafficLayer.setMap(gmap.mapObject);

    map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(-2, 50.9).transform(
        new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
        map.getProjectionObject()
    ), 10);

}
```

However our site uses a set of standard base maps and we would like to be able to display the traffic layer over these. Is this possible?

We would also be interested in being able to display Google weather and the Streetview overlay in a similar fashion.

Our site already uses Spherical Mercator projection so this is not an issue.

Answer (score 3):

From the Google Maps Terms of service:

> (h) **No Use of Content without a Google Map**. You must not use or
>   display the Content without a corresponding Google map, unless you are
>   explicitly permitted to do so in the Maps APIs Documentation. In any
>   event, you must not use or display the Content on or in conjunction
>   with a non-Google map. For example, you must not use geocodes obtained
>   through the Service in conjunction with a non-Google map. As another
>   example, you must not display Street View imagery alongside a
>   non-Google map, but you may display Street View imagery without a
>   corresponding Google map because the Maps APIs Documentation
>   explicitly permits you to do so.

In short, you can't use Google Maps content with a non-Google map, but you can use it **without** a map, depending on what the API documentation says.